# Selection bugs make Mathematica 10 unusable

Tags: front-end, bugs, editing

I'm getting odd selection bugs in *Mathematica* (starting in 10.0.1.0, OS X 10.10 and still present in 10.3.1.0, OS X 10.11.2) that are making it impossible to use. For example if I simply click before the 'i' in `With` I get

[image]

while if I click after the 't' I get

[image]

and if I click after the '=' in `mp =` I get

[image]

Attempts to drag out a selection produce similarly bizzare results, with the selection extending several to many characters ahead of the dragged location, in starts and fits; while double-clicking selects huge blocks of code.

This happens in fresh notebooks in fresh *Mathematica* sessions into which any amount of code has been pasted or typed. Obviously this makes it impossible to get anything done. Has anyone else seen this bug? Is there something I could reset or disable that might be the cause?

Comment: When you state "click before the 'i'" do you mean click and then drag or is Mathematica decided that you must want to select something with a single left-click of the mouse button?

Comment: have you tried blowing away the FE caches (`$UserBaseDirectory\FrontEnd\`)?

Comment: @bobthechemist: Just click; no dragging at all. *Mathematica* is doing the rest on its own.

Comment: @rcollyer: No. What are those and how do I do that?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius go to the directory I pointed out above, and delete the directories with `Cache` in their name. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @rcollyer On my machine (Win7 x64) these directories are located in `$HomeDirectory <> "/AppData/Local/Mathematica/FrontEnd"`.

Comment: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464

Comment: @rcollyer: Wolfram's "support" explains: "This sounds like a dirty track pad or a faulty mouse." FWIW: I didn't see selection or responsiveness issues in ANY other applications, and removing caches fixed the issue (for now).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius thanks for the info.

Comment: @rcollyer: No further interest from Mathematica ("Premier") "Support" other than to blame the mouse.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I don't know what to tell you. But, I will keep an eye out for it.

Comment: @rcollyer: Thanks! And if you have any ideas on how to get Wolfram's "Support" to work, let me know.

Comment: @rcollyer: Update. The bug us back. Still no interest in this problem from Wolfram's expensive "Support".

Comment: Have you tried dropping back to 9 to make sure the bug goes away?

Comment: @rogerl: I'm not sure why I'd want to do that.

Comment: Well, up to you, obviously, but a) if you still have it on your machine it's easy to try, and b) if the bug does go away you have something definitive you can go back to Wolfram with.

Comment: @rogerl: I think I have something pretty definitive to discuss with Wolfram now. Better would be this: Open *Mathematica*, create a new notebook, select the first line of code in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102750/37) (from the `s` to the `;`), copy and paste into the new notebook; then click somewhere in the pasted text. What do you see?

Comment: I see exactly what I expect; the cursor ends up between two appropriate characters, and nothing is selected.

Comment: @rogerl: OK, now bookmark this and try that now and again over the next months. Eventually you'll get the same behavior I see. Try to note *anything* that you can that might be different about the time the but appears (I can't) and let me know here. Once it starts happening it should keep happening for a while.

Comment: I just noticed the length of time between your deleting the cache info and the bug reappearing. Certainly suggests crap building up somewhere. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: @rogerl: Any idea why this should appear only (at least now) in new notebooks? I can past exactly the same text into and existing or even a duplicate ("Save As...") notebook and not get the error.

Comment: @rogerl: I'm pretty sure the cache has nothing to do with it. This spans version updates.

Comment: No ideas, sorry. All seems pretty odd.

Comment: @rogerl: No kidding. Out of the blue I'm just shut down, and without any support (for the *most expensive* app I own!)!

Comment: I'm not seeing any such difficulty with your code in *Mathematica* 10.3.1 under OS X 10.11.2 (El Capitan).

Comment: If you want folks to try to replicate the errant behavior your report, please edit the question so as to include displayed copyable code -- not just an image.

Comment: @murray: Paste anything at all into a new (and sometimes existing) notebook.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: I don't understand your comment about pasting anything into a new notebook -- what about doing that? (I copy and paste between notebooks all the time without difficulty.)

Comment: @murray: So do I most of the time; and I don't understand it either. But after months of working, I can do almost anything (pasting seems to be the trigger) and then I get this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar thing start happening to me. I think it is, in fact, related to a bad/dirty mouse combined with some weird modal-selection behavior in Mathematica on a double-click (in my case, Mathematica 11.3 on OSX 10.14).

One can single-click to place the insert cursor within a word, or double-click to select the entire world (another click to select the entire line). Once we've entered word or line-select mode, then for the next few seconds I am unable to single-clock to insert the cursor within a different word. Instead it will stay in word-select mode and select the entire new word (and then we are in word-select mode for several more seconds).

It was extremely frustrating until I learned the following trick: "when you are stuck in this mode, instead of frantically clicking around trying to get out of it--instead just count to 5 before clicking again on the new word. works every time".

By the way, the reason I think that a "bad mouse" is a contributing factor is that a common failure mode of bad/dirty mouse is that they start registering double-clicks on a single-click. That puts one into word-selection mode accidentally and then we're trapped until we do the "count to 5" thing.