# How do I plot EventSeries?

Tags: plotting, time-series

The [documentation that I can find](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/time-series/represent-time-series-data-with-timeseries-and-eve.html) suggests that I should be able to plot an `EventSeries` with `DateListPlot`. But this doesn't work for me.

For example

```
sunrises=Sunrise[DateRange[DateObject[{2014,1,1}],DateObject[{2015,1,1}],{5,"Day"}]];
DateListPlot[sunrises]
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that `Sunrise` packages up an `EventSeries` that is kind of wonky for what you are trying to do. The values are all `DateObject` which don't lend themselves to plotting on the y-axis.

```
sunrises=Sunrise[DateRange[DateObject[{2014,1,1}],DateObject[{2015,1,1}],{5,"Day"}]];

sunrises["Values"][[1]] // InputForm
(* DateObject[{2014, 1, 1}, TimeObject[{7, 29}, TimeZone -> -6.], TimeZone -> -6.] *)
```

What you want to visualize is the time of day so you need to convert those values. Since all of the time series functionality works with `EventSeries` you can use `TimeSeriesMap`.

```
DateListPlot@TimeSeriesMap[(#["Hour24"] + #["Minute"]/60) &, sunrises]
```

[image]

Comment: How do I get rid of the "chunkiness" of the plot? It should be much smoother.

Answer (score 5):

I found the predictive interface helpful for working out the following.

```
sunrises = 
  Sunrise[
    DateRange[DateObject[{2014, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2015, 1, 1}], 
    {5, "Day"}]]["Values"];
times = 
  Module[{h, m}, 
    {h, m} = DateValue[#, {"Hour", "Minute"}]; 
    h + m/60.]& /@ sunrises;
DateListPlot[Transpose[{sunrises, times}]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: How you yo get a TARDIS?!

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius. There is one built into every _Mathematica_ notebook :-) Really, between the predictive interface and the documentation, it only took a few minutes to work this out.

Answer (score 2):

```
sunrises = DateRange[DateObject[{2014, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2015, 1, 1}], {5, "Day"}];

DateListPlot@Transpose[{sunrises, DateList /@ Sunrise /@ sunrises /. 
  {_, _, _, h_, m_, _} :> h + m/60.}]
```

[image]

Comment: How do I examine an `EventSeries` to discover that this is necessary?

Comment: You need two different things. (1) dates, here `sunrises`, and (2) values, here `h + m/60.`. Dates and values have to be transposed do that every date has a value attached. `{{{2014, 1, 1}, value1}, {{2014, 1, 2}, value2}, ...}`